# How to catch Exception like in a FrontController in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Basically every repository method can possibly throw a DataAccessException . A lot of exceptions inherit from DataAccessException. So maybe I will catch DuplicateKeyException or maybe DataIntegrityViolationException . But all the other say 40 - 50 exceptions I will not catch explicitly. Instead I will just catch DataAccessException . So why always catch DataAccessException  ?? Instead I would prefer catching it just once. But how to do that in Spring. There is no Front Controller. There are just Controllers. So how should I catch it in a central place. The only place I know whould be start of Spring. But I don't think that works.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
        catch(DataAccessException e)
        {
              //Do your error handling here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't catch exception for an error caused during execution of a request on try-catch on `SpringApplication.run`. Each requests are processed in their own thread within the *Mapping method on @Controller/@RestController class. You can use @ControllerAdvice or @ExceptionHandler. Lookup online on how to use those.

Comment: There is a possibility for this exception to be caught in your main class if your application fails to start due to problem occurred in the DAO layer but it's not standard to catch DAO exceptions here in the main class...It should be handled in the DAO layer itself

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the exceptions at the beans or controllers that has the code managing db access, you can catch and manage this each controller bu the better approach is to implement an exception handler as th guid is showing here https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: Ok thanks. But why actually is this not working. This is the starting point of every Spring application and every not caught exception should end up here in the highest layer. But no.   try {
  SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println("Bla Bla");
  }

Comment: @Josephine, even if you start your app by running main method containing `SpringApplication.run`, your http requests are handled in separate thread. You need to either manually handle the exception in each *Mapping method or use @ControllerAdvice or @ExceptionHandler.

Comment: ah ok. I did not know that main method is in different thread than all the controllers. Where can I read this up

Comment: you can read how  its work in the official documentation. Spring has a very detailed doc. I suggest to read it. But before that, you  should have a basic understand to how web servers and threading works.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified process:

The run method call starts an embadded web server (and the whole spring infrastructure). So actually for example if you try to print out something after run call, it would not appear on the console.
The webserver runs and dispatch your requests in different threads. So the exception will happen on that threads. Spring use lot of exception handlers etc in the background.
So it more complicated in the reality. But you may see that this is not a simple, single threaded application.

The previous answer shows how to handle the exceptions in central place. For simple mvc application, I suggest to use  `@ControllerAdvice`

Comment: it's funny. If you have a try..catch around the start method SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);   then the whitelabel error is not displayed !!!

Comment: so in my opinion Spring is very complex. You never know what happens or can you explain why whitelabel error is not shown in the above described case ?    public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
  SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println("Bla Bla");
  }
 }

Comment: You should learn multithreading in Java and Spring. After that you will know what happen and when. It is not magic, but must learn to understand. You can check my simplified example above (the exception happens in worker thread wont propagate to the main thread).

Answer (score 0):

To catch the exceptions in one central place you can use a common class annotated with ControllerAdvice. Below is a snippet for reference,

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomizedExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException .class)
   public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> externalIdmException(DataAccessException ex,
        WebRequest request) {
    // exception handling
   }
}
```

This Class will catch exceptions of type to which it is defined in a central place. If you want more specific exceptions to be handled at the class level, @ExceptionHandler method can be preferred.